# Help understanding the definition of a parametrization

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Definition from Flanigan's *Complex Variables*:

A function $\alpha:[a,b] \to \Gamma$, $\alpha(t)=(\alpha_1(t),\alpha_2(t))$ is called a *parametrization* of $\Gamma$ if and only if

$(i).$ $\alpha$ is continuous

$(ii).$ $\alpha$ maps $[a,b]$ to $\Gamma$ i.e. each $z \in \Gamma$ is of the form $z= \alpha(t)$ for at least one $t \in [a,b]$

Question: For condition $(ii)$ could we just say $\alpha$ is surjective? It seems like that's what the author is requiring without explicitly writing it. The definition for a surjective function $\alpha$ looks similar, but is written slightly different: For every $z \in \Gamma$, there is a $t \in [a,b]$ such that $z=\alpha(t)$.

Comment: The definition for a surjective function doesn't just "look similar," it is the same (although, yes, "written slightly different").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is exactly a surjective (onto) mapping, mapping the interval *onto* the curve. (With every image point on the curve being a function of $t \in [a,b]$.)